# Ext.draw.Text dynamically change text

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

How to change text dynamically on Ext.draw.Text element?

```
this.textLabel = Ext.create "Ext.draw.Text"
        type  : 'text',
        text  : me.curValue,
        font  : '24px Arial',
        width : 100,
        height: 30,
        x : 100 
        y : 120
```

This method doesn't work:

```
   this.textLabel.setText("new text")
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if its a typo but your code should look something like this:

```
this.textLabel = Ext.create('Ext.draw.Text', {
    type  : 'text',
    text  : me.curValue,
    font  : '24px Arial',
    width : 100,
    height: 30,
    x : 100, 
    y : 120
});

this.textLabel.setText("new text");
```

Also what does `this` and `me` refer to? More code would be helpful.
Anyways here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/6zczP/2/

Comment: Yes,problem was in structure of components, i added Ext.draw.Text as item of Chart, and it doesnt work correctly. Thanks for answered